# I want to change picture of a div on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[image]

I implemented a jQuery functionality to open a close div on click. I set a plus sign in the div while unclicked; when the div is clicked, I want the plus sign to be changed as minus. However, I'm running into trouble doing that. This is what I've coded so far:

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper"> 
        <div id="content">  
            <div class="demo">
                <h2 align="center">DASHBOARD</h2>
                <h3 class="expand collapse-close" ">STPCODE NOT REGISTERED &nbsp;&nbsp; 10 <span></span>  </h3>      
                <div class="collapse">
                    <p>List of unregistered user are here</p>
                </div>                    

                <h3 class="expand collapse-close">REGISTERED USERS IN DRAFT MODE 10 <span></span> </h3>
                <div class="collapse">
                    <p>List of  user in draft mode are here</p>
                </div>                    
                <h3 class="expand collapse-close">PAYMENT INITIATED FOR USERS 10<span></span> </h3>
                <div class="collapse">
                    <p>Total number of users who have their payment initiated</p>
                </div>                   
                <h3 class="expand collapse-close"> PAYMENT RECIEVED FOR USERS 10 <span></span> </h3>
                <div class="collapse">
                    <p>Total number of users who have their payment received</p>
                </div>                       
                <h3 class="expand collapse-close">PAYMENT  DISAPPROVED FOR USERS 10<span></span> </h3>
                <div class="collapse">
                    <p>Total number of users who have their payment disapproved</p>
                </div>            
            </div>          
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
/* --------
The CSS rules offered here are just an example, you may use them as a base. 
--------- */
 * {
    margin:0;
    padding:0
}
/* --- Page Structure  --- */
 #wrapper {
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:15px 15% 8em;
    text-align:left
}
#content {
    max-width:70em;
    width:70%;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding-bottom:20px;
    overflow:hidden
}
.demo {
    margin:1.5em 0;
    padding:1.5em 1.5em 0.75em;
    /*  border:1px solid #ccc; */
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden
}
.collapse p {
    padding:0 10px 1em
}
.switch {
    position:absolute;
    top:1.5em;
    right: 1.5em;
    padding:3px
}
.post .switch {
    position:static;
    text-align:right
}
.post .main {
    margin-bottom:.3em;
    padding-bottom:0
}
.other li, .summary {
    margin-bottom:.3em;
    padding:1em;
    border:1px solid #e8e7e8;
    background-color:#f8f7f8
}
.other ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    text-align:center
}
/* --- Headings  --- */
 .expand {
    padding-bottom:.75em;
    background-color: #CFDEFF;
    border:1px solid #FFFFFF;
}
.expand a {
    color:#2A51A0;
}
.expand a span {
    padding-left:100px;
}
.collapse-close span {
    display:block;
    float:right;
    background:url(images/plus.png) center center no-repeat;
    padding:10px;
}
#collapse-close {
    display:block;
    float:right;
    background:url(images/minus.png) center center no-repeat;
    padding:10px;
}
```

jQuery:

```
<!--//--><![CDATA[//><!--
    $(function() {
        $("#content h3.expand").toggler();
        $("#content div.demo").expandAll({trigger: "h3.expand", ref: "h3.expand"});
        $("#content div.other").expandAll({
            expTxt : "[Show]", 
            cllpsTxt : "[Hide]",
            ref : "ul.collapse",
            showMethod : "show",
            hideMethod : "hide"

        });

        $("#content div.post").expandAll({
            expTxt : "[Read this entry]", 
            cllpsTxt : "[Hide this entry]",
            ref : "div.collapse", 
            localLinks: "p.top a"    
        });    
    });
//--><!]]>
```

Can anyone help me to change the plus sign to minus when I click on that panel? Conversely, a plus sign should appear when the panel is collapsed back.

Library/ scripts:

- jQuery 1.4.2
- javascript/expand.js

i am doing this in my code

function aMethod(){

```
    $(function() {
       $( "#expand" ).click(function() {
         $( "#collapse" ).toggleClass( "collapse-close collapse-open");
       });
     });

}

</script>
   </head>

     <body>
      <div id="wrapper"> 
     <div id="content">  
         <div class="demo">
              <h2 align="center">DASHBOARD</h2>

     <h3 class="expand collapse-close" onclick="aMethod();">STPCODE NOT REGISTERED &nbsp;&nbsp; 10 <span></span>  </h3>      
          <div class="collapse">
            <p>List of unregistered user are here</p>
           </div>
```

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle? because some syntax error in your HTML. Also in your CSS you have like `#collapse-close{`. But there is no element with the ID collapse-close. so if you create fiddle we can easily identify your code problem.

Comment: i dont know how to create fiddle

Answer (score 2):

use `.toggleClass( className )`

**Refernce :** http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/

Comment: where i will use that can you plese be some specific

Answer (score 2):

Like @Rajesh Kumar already said, you can use `jQuery .toggleClass()`.

```
<div class="first"></div>

$("div").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('second');
});
```

Have a look at that **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mea7a3aL/2/)**

Another way would be working with `.addClass()` and `.removeClass()`. It's equivalent to `.toggleClass()`.

You can watch this **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pddtuwh8/)** for a demo working with `.addClass()` and `.removeClass()`.

```
<div class="first"></div>

$("div").click(function(){
    if($("div").hasClass("first")){
        $(this).removeClass("first");
        $(this).addClass("second");
    }

    else{
        $(this).removeClass("second");
        $(this).addClass("first");
    }
});
```

But I suggest you to use `.toggleClass()`. It's less code, which does the same, just easier and more clear.

Comment: function aMethod(){
 
 $("h3").click(function(){
     $(this).toggleClass('collapse-open');
 });

} this is i am doing but working properly

Answer (score 0):

#### Changes

```
#collapse-close {
    display:block;
    float:right;
    background:url(images/minus.png) center center no-repeat;
    padding:10px;
}
```

#### into

```
.collapse-open span{
    background:url(images/minus.png) center center no-repeat;
}
```

#### and use jquery toggleClass method in your function/jquery code like :

```
.toggleClass('collapse-close collapse-open')
```

Comment: please see my edited code portion  it is not working

Answer (score 0):

Implemented what you need without expand.js
Have a look, it might help:

```
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        /* --------
        The CSS rules offered here are just an example, you may use them as a base. 
        --------- */
        * {margin:0; padding:0}
        /* --- Page Structure  --- */


        #wrapper{
            margin:0 auto;
            padding:15px 15% 8em;
            text-align:left
        }
        #content {
            max-width:70em;
            width:70%;
            margin:0 auto;
            padding-bottom:20px;
            overflow:hidden
        }
        .demo {
            margin:1.5em 0;
            padding:1.5em 1.5em 0.75em;
            /*  border:1px solid #ccc; */
            position:relative;
            overflow:hidden
        }
        .collapse p {padding:0 10px 1em}

        .switch {position:absolute; top:1.5em; right: 1.5em; padding:3px}

        .post .switch {position:static; text-align:right}

        .post .main{margin-bottom:.3em; padding-bottom:0}

        .other li, .summary {margin-bottom:.3em; padding:1em; border:1px solid #e8e7e8; background-color:#f8f7f8}

        .other ul {list-style-type:none; text-align:center}

        /* --- Headings  --- */


        .expand{padding-bottom:.75em;background-color: #CFDEFF; border:1px solid #FFFFFF;   }
        .expand a{color:#2A51A0;}
        .expand a span {padding-left:100px;}

        .collapse-close span {
            display:block;
            float:right;
            background-size: 20px;
            padding:10px;
        }

        .collapse {
            transition: 1s;
        }

        .plus {
            background:url(http://png-2.findicons.com/files/icons/1007/crystal_like/256/plus.png) center center no-repeat;
        }

        .minus {
            background:url(http://i492.photobucket.com/albums/rr281/neversinned/design/icons/256x256/panel/minus.png) center center no-repeat;
        }

        .display-none {
            display: none;
        }

        .trigger{
            cursor: pointer;
        }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.collapse-close span').click(function(){
            debugger;
                if(this.classList.contains('plus')){
                    this.classList.remove("plus");
                    this.classList.add("minus");
                    $(this.parentElement.parentElement).children(".collapse").removeClass('display-none');
                }
                else{
                    this.classList.remove("minus");
                    this.classList.add("plus");
                    $(this.parentElement.parentElement).children(".collapse").addClass('display-none');
                }
            })
            $('.trigger').click(function(){
                if(this.classList.contains('expand-all')){
                    $('.collapse-close span').each(function(){
                        this.classList.remove("plus");
                        this.classList.add("minus");
                        $(this.parentElement.parentElement).children(".collapse").removeClass('display-none');
                    });
                    this.classList.remove('expand-all');
                    this.classList.add('collapse-all');
                    $(this).html('[Collapse All]');
                }
                else {
                    $('.collapse-close span').each(function(){
                        this.classList.remove("minus");
                        this.classList.add("plus");
                        $(this.parentElement.parentElement).children(".collapse").addClass('display-none');
                    });
                    this.classList.remove('collapse-all');
                    this.classList.add('expand-all');
                    $(this).html('[Expand All]');
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="content">
            <div class="demo">
                <h2 align="center">DASHBOARD</h2>
                <div class='trigger expand-all'>[Expand All]</div>
                <div class="ques-ans">
                    <h3 class="expand collapse-close">STPCODE NOT REGISTERED &nbsp;&nbsp; 10 <span class="plus"></span></h3>
                    <div class="collapse display-none">
                        <p>List of unregistered user are here</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="ques-ans">
                    <h3 class="expand collapse-close">REGISTERED USERS IN DRAFT MODE 10 <span class="plus"></span></h3>
                    <div class="collapse display-none">
                        <p>List of  user in draft mode are here</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="ques-ans">
                    <h3 class="expand collapse-close">PAYMENT INITIATED FOR USERS 10<span class="plus"></span></h3>
                    <div class="collapse display-none">
                        <p>Total number of users who have their payment initiated</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="ques-ans">
                    <h3 class="expand collapse-close"> PAYMENT RECIEVED FOR USERS 10 <span class="plus"></span></h3>
                    <div class="collapse display-none">
                        <p>Total number of users who have their payment received</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="ques-ans">
                    <h3 class="expand collapse-close">PAYMENT  DISAPPROVED FOR USERS 10<span class="plus"></span></h3>
                    <div class="collapse display-none">
                        <p>Total number of users who have their payment disapproved</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>          
    </div>
</body>
```